# numpy sum axis intuition

Tags: python, numpy, sum, axis

I've always thought that axis 0 is row-wise and 1 is column-wise.

```
  row-wise (axis 0) ---> [[ 0  1]   
                          [ 0  5]]  
                            ↑
                            |
                          column-wise (axis 1)
```

However, the numpy result is the exact opposite of how I'm thinking.

```
>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=0)
array([0, 6])

>>> np.sum([[0, 1], [0, 5]], axis=1)
array([1, 5])
```

What am I thinking wrong? Am I the only one who's wondering this?

Comment: Other way around. Axis 0 doesn't go in the row direction; for example, indexing along axis 0 like `a[0]` produces rows not because axis 0 is in the row direction, but because it *eliminates* axis 0, which was the column direction.

Comment: For 2d this use of `axis` can be ambiguous, one is summed and one is left, but which.  It is clearer if you think about 1d or 3d arrays.  In 3d, if you sum axis 1, you are left with the other 2.